# Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar

Tags: android, kotlin

Without remembering since when, I got this error message on every `./gradlew build`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.CoreLibraryRewriter.reader(CoreLibraryRewriter.java:44)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:388)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:326)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:280)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:584)

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/43.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/46.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/3.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/2.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/5.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/30.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/33.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/15.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/18.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/6.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/9.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/25.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/28.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/1.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/4.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/36.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/39.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/tmp/kapt3/classes/debug --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/2 --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/10.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/13.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/42.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/45.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/23.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/26.jar --input /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/14.jar --output /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/desugar/debug/17.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/tmp/kapt3/classes/debug --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/0.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/1.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/2.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/3.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/4.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/5.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/6.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/7.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/8.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/9.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/10.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/11.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/12.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/13.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/14.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/15.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/16.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/17.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/18.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/19.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/20.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/21.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/22.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/23.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/24.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/25.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/26.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/27.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/28.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/29.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/30.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/31.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/32.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/33.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/34.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/35.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/36.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/37.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/38.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/39.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/40.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/41.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/42.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/43.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/44.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/45.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/46.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/47.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/48.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/49.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/50.jar --classpath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Documents/GitHub/wp-android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/stackFramesFixer/debug/51.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/android.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Users/hendraanggrian/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-26/optional/org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 14 --desugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}
```

Any idea what might have caused it? I tried:

- Changing jdk from embed, 8, and 9
- multidex
- proguard

None of which seems to work. The source can be found [here](https://github.com/WijayaPrinting/wp-android), any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try cleaning your project and use invalidate cache/restart

Comment: Unfortunately, invalidate cache and restart doesn't seem to help. Upgrading to newest Android Studio 3.0.1 also doesn't.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#supported_features)?

Comment: Any update on this? I'm stuck exactly with the same issue